Problem with texlive-2024.20241102 with TikZ markers set inside a Minted environment
Recently (last Tuesday, I think) I updated my TexLive distribution to 2024.20241102 with Minted 3.x, since then I noticed that the way I managed to set Tikz markers inside a Minted environment to point some elements inside code is not working anymore.
Here is a (hopefully) minimal sample of the way I was doing:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

%% Workaround the 'no-space inside tags for Minted' problem
\tikzstyle{remember} = [remember picture]
\tikzstyle{marker} = [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt]

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{text}
A sentence with a special |\tikz[remember]\node[marker](mark1){mark};|.
\end{minted}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[->,very thick] (mark1.south) -- (mark1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Unfortunately, since my update of TexLive, I get the following error on my first attempt to build the document (I build with rubber but this is about the same with pdflatex):
rubber --pdf sample
compiling sample.tex
executing: pdflatex \nonstopmode \input{sample.tex}
Running pdflatex resulted in a non-zero exit status.
There were errors compiling sample.tex: Recipe for sample.pdf failed.
./sample.tex:17: Package pgf Error: No shape named `mark1' is known.
./sample.tex:17: leading text:   \draw[->,very thick] (mark1.south)
./sample.tex:17: Package pgf Error: No shape named `mark1' is known.
./sample.tex:17: leading text: ...very thick] (mark1.south) -- (mark1.south)
error: Stopping because of compilation errors.

Then, on a second try, it build properly.
I noticed that I get the errors again each time I remove the _minted/ directory, forcing the compiler to create a new one. Then, when the _minted/ directory is cached, the build goes until the end without complaining at all.
Is it a known problem on Minted 3.x ? How would you solve it ?

The error on the first run is new, but tikzmarks always needed two compilations to get the positions correctly.

Yes, this way of doing also required at least a second build, but it wasn't stopping with such an error before. This is what's puzzling me. ;-)

You can avoid the error during the first run with the highlightmode=immediate option. That's slower and you will still need to compile a second time to get the correct position.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[highlightmode=immediate]{minted}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{remember} = [remember picture]
\tikzstyle{marker} = [inner sep=0pt,outer sep=2pt]

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{text}
A sentence with a special |\tikz[remember]\node[marker](mark1){mark};|.
\end{minted}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \draw[->,very thick] (mark1.south) -- (mark1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot!!!

@perror You're welcome!
